# AJAX não está a funcionar

Tags: ajax

Alguém sabe porque esse `AJAX` não está a funcionar? As variáveis estão a receber os valores, só a parte de mandar os dados para `actualiza.php` é que não funciona.

```
$("#btnedit").click(function(){
        var proc=$("#procedit").val();
        var nome=$("#nomeedit").val();  
        var cc=$("#ccedit").val();
        var data_nasc=$("#data_nascedit").val();

        alert(proc);
        alert(nome);
        alert(cc);
        alert(data_nasc);

            $.post("actualiza.php",{ proc: proc, nome: nome, cc: cc, data_nasc: data_nasc },
                function(data)
                {
                        $("html").html(data);
                });      

        });
```

Comment: O que `actualiza.php` deveria retornar? Se possivel, adicione o trecho de retorno dessa pagina.

Comment: Já verificou se uma requisição é enviada para "actualiza.php"? Qual o critério para determinar se falhou? o conteúdo esperado não é adicionado ao elemento "html"? Por que  falha pode estar no script PHP também.

Comment: No `actualiza.php` apenas tenho para receber as variáveis e mostrá-las assim:
`<?
   $n_proc = $_POST['proc'];
   $nome = $_POST['nome'];
   $cc = $_POST['cc'];
   $data_nasc = $_POST['data_nasc'];

   echo $n_proc;
   echo $nome;
   echo $cc;
   echo $data_nasc;
?>`

Comment: Testei esse código aqui, e como eu imaginava, uma requisição é enviada normalmente.

Comment: Faltava um `}` no código `php`, é que tinha feito um `if` antes de mandar as variáveis e não tinha fechado o ciclo. Mas pensava mesmo que tinha feito o AJAX mal. Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa analisar melhor isso pra identificar onde exatamente está o problema. Verifique se uma requisição é realmente feita. Verifique o status dessa requisição. Verifique aquela "function" é executada ...

Comment: Ok, então esta resolvido :D